# Activity Recognition Running permissions in android 6.0

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow, activity-recognition

I'm trying to implement activity recognition so it will support api 23.
I've followed the running permissions guide from  here :

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html#normal-dangerous

And i cant find if activity recognition is classified as dangerous permission or normal?

Even in google's activity recognition sample they dont target api 23 : https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location/tree/master/ActivityRecognition

is it possible that activity recoognition is not supported in android 6.0?

Comment: What specific permission(s) do you need for activity recognition?

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION" />

Comment: That's strange. [This sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Permissions/PermissionReporter) builds a roster of all detected permissions, and I am not seeing that one when running it on an Android 6.0 device.

Comment: Maybe activity recognition is not yet supported in android 6.0?

Comment: I would think that it is more likely that this specific permission may have been dropped or replaced by a different permission (e.g., `BODY_SENSORS`). I have not used the Play Services activity recognition APIs, so I do not know what may have changed with it related to Android 6.0.

Comment: Thanks, it would be helpful if google was updating what was changed in all those api's such as : Activity recognition , geofencing and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use this permission in my app and it doesn't require any extra effort on Android 6, you can use it without any problem, it's not "dangerous".

Comment: Thanks , how did you figured out it's not "dangerous" in android 6?

Comment: Because I tested it and my app works on android 6 :)

Comment: Sounds great , will try to test it on android 6 too soon :)

Answer (score 3):

In the following link you can find more details about permissions in android 23

http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/things-you-need-to-know-about-android-m-permission-developer-edition/en

The following permissions are automatically granted

```
android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS
android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE
android.permission.ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY
android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE
android.permission.ACCESS_WIMAX_STATE
android.permission.BLUETOOTH
android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN
android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY
android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE
android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE
android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE
android.permission.CHANGE_WIMAX_STATE
android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD
android.permission.EXPAND_STATUS_BAR
android.permission.FLASHLIGHT
android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS
android.permission.GET_PACKAGE_SIZE
android.permission.INTERNET
android.permission.KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES
android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS
android.permission.NFC
android.permission.READ_SYNC_SETTINGS
android.permission.READ_SYNC_STATS
android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED
android.permission.REORDER_TASKS
android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES
android.permission.SET_TIME_ZONE
android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER
android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER_HINTS
android.permission.SUBSCRIBED_FEEDS_READ
android.permission.TRANSMIT_IR
android.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT
android.permission.VIBRATE
android.permission.WAKE_LOCK
android.permission.WRITE_SYNC_SETTINGS
com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM
com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT
com.android.launcher.permission.UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT
```

Comment: Thanks! does that mean that all the rest are "dangerous" ?

Comment: Yes you'll have to request the permissions every time that you need it.

Comment: Sounds strange , but will try to request it .

Comment: It's wrong. This permission is not classified as dangerous.